# Не получается вывести информацию из базы данных Firebase в TextView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести данные из базы данных Firebase в TextView. 
Вот так выглядит моя база данных

[image: База данных]

У меня есть новое Activity, на которое пользователи попадают после авторизации.[image: Activity]

Мне нужно, чтобы вместо надписей "Ваше имя" и "Ваша фамилия" выводились данные из базы данных конкретного зашедшего пользователя (То есть должно быть Василий Киселев).

Вот код этой страницы

```
public class pagestudent extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView name, last_name;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        DatabaseReference users;
        FirebaseDatabase db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagestudent);
        findViewById(R.id.button_logout).setOnClickListener(this);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile);
        last_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile2);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        users.child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String myname = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                name.setText(myname);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_logout:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы успешно вышли из аккаунта", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Код Регистрации

```
package com.example.studentjournal1;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.sip.SipSession;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

public class signup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Button back, register;
    EditText emailId, nameId, last_name, middle_name, phone, password;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference users;
    FirebaseDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users");
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        findViewById(R.id.button_register).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_back).setOnClickListener(this);
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        nameId = findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        last_name = findViewById(R.id.et_last_name);
        middle_name = findViewById(R.id.et_middle_name);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.et_phone);
        password = findViewById(R.id.et_pass);
        register = findViewById(R.id.button_register);
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String email = emailId.getText().toString().trim();
        final String username = nameId.getText().toString().trim();
        final String username2 = last_name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String username3 = middle_name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String phn = phone.getText().toString().trim();
        final String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            emailId.setError("Введите Email");
            emailId.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            emailId.setError("Введите корректный Email");
            emailId.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (username.isEmpty()) {
            nameId.setError("Введите Имя");
            nameId.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (username2.isEmpty()) {
            last_name.setError("Введите Фамилию");
            last_name.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (username3.isEmpty()) {
            middle_name.setError("Введите Отчество");
            middle_name.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (phn.isEmpty()) {
            phone.setError("Введите Телефон");
            phone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (pass.isEmpty()) {
            password.setError("Введите Пароль");
            password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (pass.length() <6) {
            password.setError("Пароль должен содержать более 6 символов");
            password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             if (task.isSuccessful()){
                 User user = new User();
                 user.setEmail(emailId.getText().toString());
                 user.setName(nameId.getText().toString());
                 user.setLast_name(last_name.getText().toString());
                 user.setMiddle_name(middle_name.getText().toString());
                 user.setPhone(phone.getText().toString());
                 user.setPass(password.getText().toString());

                 users.child(user.getName()).setValue(user);

                 Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this, MainActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Регистрация прошла успешно, теперь можете пройти авторизацию", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                     if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Данный Email уже зарегистрирован", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } else {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button_register:
                registerUser();
                break;
            case R.id.button_back:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Пробовал различные варианты кода, но либо заканчивалось ошибкой (что-то то вроде нулевого объекта), либо TextView так и оставались без изменения.

Измененная версия проекта

[image: Измененная БД]

Код страницы регистрации

```
package com.example.finaljournalstudent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class signup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button back_main, register_reg;
    EditText email_str, first_name_str, last_name_str, middle_name_str, phone_str, password_str;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        findViewById(R.id.button_register).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_back).setOnClickListener(this);
        email_str = findViewById(R.id.email_reg);
        first_name_str = findViewById(R.id.first_name_reg);
        last_name_str = findViewById(R.id.last_name_reg);
        middle_name_str = findViewById(R.id.middle_name_reg);
        phone_str = findViewById(R.id.password_reg);
        password_str = findViewById(R.id.password_reg);
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String email = email_str.getText().toString().trim();
        final String first_name = first_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
        String last_name = last_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
        String middle_name = middle_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
        String phone = phone_str.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = password_str.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            email_str.setError("Введите Email");
            email_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            email_str.setError("Введите корректный Email");
            email_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (first_name.isEmpty()) {
            first_name_str.setError("Введите Имя");
            first_name_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (last_name.isEmpty()) {
            last_name_str.setError("Введите Фамилию");
            last_name_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (middle_name.isEmpty()) {
            middle_name_str.setError("Введите Отчество");
            middle_name_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (phone.isEmpty()) {
            phone_str.setError("Введите Телефон");
            phone_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            password_str.setError("Введите Пароль");
            password_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.length() < 6) {
            password_str.setError("Пароль должен содержать более 6 символов");
            password_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    String email_s = email_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String first_name_s = first_name_str.getText().toString();
                    String last_name_s = last_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String middle_name_s = middle_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String phone_s = phone_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String password_s = password_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String uid = mRef.push().getKey();
                    User users = new User(uid, email_s, first_name_s, last_name_s, middle_name_s, phone_s, password_s);
                    mRef.child(uid).setValue(users);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Регистрация прошла успешно, теперь можете пройти авторизацию", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Данный Email уже зарегистрирован", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_register:
                registerUser();
                break;
            case R.id.button_back:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

User класс

```
package com.example.finaljournalstudent;

public class User {
    public String uid,email_c,first_name_c,last_name_c, middle_name_c, phone_c, password_c;
    public User(){}

    public User(String uid, String email_c, String first_name_c, String last_name_c, String middle_name_c, String phone_c, String password_c) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.email_c = email_c;
        this.first_name_c = first_name_c;
        this.last_name_c = last_name_c;
        this.middle_name_c = middle_name_c;
        this.phone_c = phone_c;
        this.password_c = password_c;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getEmail_c() {
        return email_c;
    }

    public void setEmail_c(String email_c) {
        this.email_c = email_c;
    }

    public String getFirst_name_c() {
        return first_name_c;
    }

    public void setFirst_name_c(String first_name_c) {
        this.first_name_c = first_name_c;
    }

    public String getLast_name_c() {
        return last_name_c;
    }

    public void setLast_name_c(String last_name_c) {
        this.last_name_c = last_name_c;
    }

    public String getMiddle_name_c() {
        return middle_name_c;
    }

    public void setMiddle_name_c(String middle_name_c) {
        this.middle_name_c = middle_name_c;
    }

    public String getPhone_c() {
        return phone_c;
    }

    public void setPhone_c(String phone_c) {
        this.phone_c = phone_c;
    }

    public String getPassword_c() {
        return password_c;
    }

    public void setPassword_c(String password_c) {
        this.password_c = password_c;
    }
}
```

Измененная страница авторизации

```
package com.example.finaljournalstudent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button_signup, button_signin;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    EditText email_auth_str, password_auth_str;
    DatabaseReference mRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        email_auth_str = findViewById(R.id.email_main);
        password_auth_str = findViewById(R.id.password_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button_signup).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_signin).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void userLogin() {
        String email = email_auth_str.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = password_auth_str.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            email_auth_str.setError("Введите Email");
            email_auth_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            email_auth_str.setError("Введите корректный Email");
            email_auth_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            password_auth_str.setError("Введите Пароль");
            password_auth_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.length() <6) {
            password_auth_str.setError("Пароль должен содержать более 6 символов");
            password_auth_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, studentpage.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
        if(currentUser != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, studentpage.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_signup:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, signup.class));
                break;
            case R.id.button_signin:
                userLogin();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Как итог, в TextView ничего не выводится

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
public class Username {
String email;
String last_name;
String middle_name;
String name;
String pass;
String phone;

public Username(String email, String last_name, String middle_name, String name, String pass, String phone) {
    this.email = email;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.middle_name = middle_name;
    this.name = name;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public Username() {
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getMiddle_name() {
    return middle_name;
}

public void setMiddle_name(String middle_name) {
    this.middle_name = middle_name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

}

Использовать так:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Username myname = dataSnapshot.getValue(Username.class);
    name.setText(myname.getLast_name());
}
```

P.S. Плюс ко всему у вас указан некорректный путь.
Как у гугла с кириллицей не знаю, но попробуйте так(у вас как минимум в проекте user, а в базе данных userS):

```
String username = "Василий";
users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
users.child(username).addValueEventListener(/.../)
```

Comment: Класс User у меня уже есть в проекте, возможно ошибка в пути, но так как относительно недавно занялся Android Studio я не очень понимаю как должно быть, если есть возможность помочь, буду признателен

Comment: Внес правку, попробуйте и используйте класс User который создали или мой пример.

Comment: К сожалению никакого результата не дало. Про User я еще сразу заметил и уже исправил. И какой то странный вывод через String username "Василий", вроде так не должно быть. Может быть какая то проблема именно в записи информации о пользователе в базу данных? (Прикрепил дополнительно класс с регистрацией)

Comment: Исходя из приведенного вами кода и скриншота базы, путь к имени у вас Users/Василий/name, вы же сразу пытаетесь обратиться как Users/name. Получите имя пользователя из mAuth и используйте его в пути, то есть users.child(Имя пользователя).addValueEventListener() и далее сможете получить, например фамилию, как String myLastName = dataSnapshot.child("last_name").getValue(String.class);. Также желательно Log.v("DatabaseError", databaseError.getMessage()); в методе onCancelled чтобы вам не гадать

Comment: А как же быть тогда с другими входящими пользователями если в коде будет выбираться "Василий"? Нужно чтобы выводилась фамилия и имя для каждого пользователя свое. Ох уж эти зарубежные туториалы.. просто с толку теперь сбивают

Comment: Это уже совсем другая тема. При регистрации пользователя и записи в данных в базу данных users.child(user.getName()).setValue(user), не используйте user.getName(), посмотрите на метод getUid() у Firebase auth , тогда и в коде основной страницы спокойно сможете его получить из mAuth и использовать вместо "Василий" просто получайте это значение. users.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(/..../)

Comment: Решил переписать проект с нуля, смог сделать регистрацию через Uid (так ли в точности это делается я не уверен, но в БД вместо имени теперь выводится идентификатор). Но проблема осталась, я прописал как вы писали users.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())... и вывод в TextView, но имя по прежнему не выводится. К посту прикрепил все измененные классы

Comment: В коде регистрации String uid = mRef.push().getKey() - это не uid, метод push генерирует дочерний элемент, его ключ отличается от uid. Используйте getUid() и при регистрации.

Comment: Переделал, теперь uid ключ выглядит так "2jvcjIEytufzjH0OsgAkvyQJPfT2". Это верный вариант? Просто теперь при попытке войти в профиль сразу происходит выход на главную страницу, как будто авторизация не сработала. в Логе выдает вот это: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String. И синим цветом показывает эту строку String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); Я чувствую что я уже на верном пути, так как теперь хоть не пишет про нулевой объект, но как быть сейчас?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь приравнять hashmap к string, либо чётко указывайте какую строку хотите получить или используйте ваш класс User и уже оттуда получайте нужные данные